# What is this extra `import` keyword in my `NSManagedObjectSubClass`?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsmanagedobject

Currently I'm working with `coreData` in `Xcode 8` with `Swift 3`, after designing the table in coreData i created the `NSManagedObjectSubClass` for all my entities. After creating subclass I ended up with error, as following image,

[image]

I resolved the error by deleting this unwanted `import` statement. My question is **Why that extra unwanted import statement is created by default?**

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I had a problem like this in a beta version of Xcode 8 but it hasn't happened recently.

Comment: Apple had identified this as a fixed issue in one of the recent Xcode releases so it should be fixed if you have the current version.

Comment: Im using `Xcode 8` GM @Tom

Comment: Okay I will try by updating the Xcode version @Dan

Answer (score 1):

Update Xcode to the most current version.